# Missing type information in parameters in MINIX 3 (v3.1.0)

Tags: c, types, minix

In [kernel/proto.h](https://github.com/danielbarter/minix_book/blob/minix_book/kernel/proto.h), MINIX 3 defines two forward declarations `struct proc` and `struct timer`. However much of the type information within the parameters is missing. Examples such as `clock_t`,`U16_t`,`tmr_func_t`, and `message` are totally missing. There does not seem to be any `#include` statements in the file either, so how is the compiler not complaining?

Comment: It's probably not meant for direct inclusion.

Comment: How come the forward declarations are in there?

Comment: How should I know? Examine the rest of the source tree ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in [kernel/kernel.h](https://github.com/danielbarter/minix_book/blob/minix_book/kernel/kernel.h), where it is clear that order of inclusion of some of the header files is important.

```
/* Important kernel header files. */
#include "config.h"     /* configuration, MUST be first */
#include "const.h"      /* constants, MUST be second */
#include "type.h"       /* type definitions, MUST be third */
#include "proto.h"      /* function prototypes */
#include "glo.h"        /* global variables */
#include "ipc.h"        /* IPC constants */
#include "debug.h"      /* debugging, MUST be last kernel header */
```

Not every header file will include every other header file that it depends on. Learn to use your local search tools. Also, a google search for `clock_t` would probably be instructive. Most of the others you mentioned, don't appear to be standard C library types.

Answer (score 0):

The header file is included with other header files that validate the missing types mentioned.